# MapFragment with FragmentManager made me do it - is there a cleaner way?

Tags: android, android-fragments

So i have an app that uses a `MapFragent` in two different activities.  The first one is implemented in the xml layout of that activity but as many of you are probably aware, the only way it seems to implement another map fragment in a different activity is to do it in java like so:

```
mMapFragment = new DRPCustomMapFragment();// this is just a class extending SupportMapFragment
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mapContainer, mMapFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        fm.executePendingTransactions();
        //
```

so in `onCreate()` i am doing exactly that.  the problem is if i try to reference mMapFragment immediately after that, its still null.  so i ended up having to add this ugly block of code:

```
mMapFragment = new DRPCustomMapFragment();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mapContainer, mMapFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        fm.executePendingTransactions();
        //


        _mapContainer.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                _map = mMapFragment.getMap();
                mMapFragment
                        .setOnDragListener(new DRPMapWrapperLayout.OnDragListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDrag(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                                Log.d("ON_DRAG",
                                        String.format("ME: %s",
                                                motionEvent.getAction()));
                                if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                                    _scrollView
                                            .requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                                }
                                if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                                        || motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {

                                    _scrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                                    _locationForDrop = _map.getCameraPosition().target;                             }

                            }
                        });

                setUpMapUI();
            }
        });
```

please tell me there is a better way.. pretty please?

Comment: "but as many of you are probably aware, the only way it seems to implement another map fragment in a different activity is to do it in java" -- and your proof of this is, what, exactly?

Comment: For example, I just took [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Basic), cloned the activity, added an action bar item to switch to that second activity, and it works just fine. Both editions of the activity use layout inflation. So, please provide citations demonstrating your claim.

Comment: right.. you have to use layout inflation.. you can't just drop a map fragment in two different xml layouts.. it crashes

Comment: You are welcome to publish a sample app that demonstrates the crash. Using `setContentView()` (which, under the covers, uses layout inflation) with a `SupportMapFragment` in multiple activities works fine for me, as noted in my earlier comments. You might also consider providing links where this behavior has been cited elsewhere, since you seem to think that "many" StackOverflow readers should be "aware" of it.